# Vim-like EOL behavior in Emacs

Tags: vim-emulation

I'm trying to get Emacs to imitate Vim's EOL behavior. Namely at the end of line ("\n"), the cursor comes to a halt instead of progressing to the start of the next line.

The following works fine and dandy but the cursor gets stuck before empty lines:

```
(defun make-eol-intangible ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook 
    (lambda ()
      (when (and (point) (looking-at "\n"))
        (backward-char)) t t)))
```

I could put an additional condition that tests for (point) looking-back however Emacs docs mention that looking-back should be avoided, and is possibly deprecated. On that note it's probably less optimal to use looking-at either.

I would like some suggestions.

---

Amended function (doesn't work as expected):

```
(defun make-eol-intangible ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook 
    (lambda ()
      (when (and (eq (char-before (point)) ?\n) 
                 (eq (char-after (point)) ?\.))
    (backward-char)))))

(make-eol-intangible)
```

Comment: When should the cursor "come to a halt"? When `forward-char` is invoked? Why are you checking `(point)` in a condition? It will always return non-`nil`. `looking-at` uses regexps, but you don't need a regexp to detect a newline. `following-char`, `char-after`, `preceding-char`, and `char-before` can all be used to detect a newline character after or before point, respectively.

Comment: What @Basil said. Please try to clarify the behavior you want. Don't assume that readers will know what the Vim behavior is. Specify the desired behavior. That will help others help you better.

Comment: What was not so clear about this description? : "I'm trying to get Emacs to imitate Vim's EOL behavior. Namely at the end of line ("\n"), the cursor comes to a halt instead of progressing to the start of the next line."

Comment: @OS2 In Emacs, when point is at the end of the line, it does not progress to the start of the next line on its own. A key/command has to be invoked in order for point to move to the next line. So which key/command are you trying to customise in order for point not to move to the next line? In other words, please describe the sequence of keys/commands you would like to invoke and what you would like to see as a result of that key/command sequence. Otherwise what you are asking is not very clear.

Comment: There's a difference between EOL and \n. But when the editor reads a \n it sends the cursor to the next line. This is what I want to avoid. This problem doesn't seem to be as trivial as it sounds. I've been playing around with elisp and this is what I've come up with but it doesn't work. `(when (and (eq (char-before (point)) ?\n) (eq (char-after (point)) ?\.)) (backward-char))`

Comment: What do you mean by "the editor reads a \n" and "it sends the cursor to the next line"? What prompts the editor to read the "\n"? In what way does it send the cursor anywhere? What is prompting these operations? And why are you checking for a full stop `?.` at point?

Comment: That's not a full stop.
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression

Comment: @OS2 Yes it is. `char-after` returns either a character integer or `nil`. `eq` on integers and symbols tests for object identity. `?\.`, usually written as `?.`, is a character integer with decimal value `46`. Your second "amended function" example does not use any regexps. For information on Elisp regexps, I'd suggest the Elisp reference manual instead: [`(info "(elisp) Regular Expressions")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html).

Comment: @OS2 Please extend your question with information on your motivation for this customisation, and precise details on how you intend to use it in practice. Otherwise it is confusing at best, and an example of an XY problem at worst.

Comment: Avoid using post-command-hook for this. Instead write your own forward char and backward char functions, and bind them to appropriate keys.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines.

```
(defun make-eol-intangible ()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook 
    (lambda ()
      (when (and (eq (char-before (point)) ?\n)
                 (not (eq (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position))))
        (left-char)))))
```

---

Found a better solution:

```el
(defun my-maybe-right ()
  "Move right if char at point is not a newline."
  (interactive)
  (unless (= (following-char) ?\n) (forward-char)))

(global-set-key [right] #'my-maybe-right)
```

Comment: `(global-set-key [right] #'my-maybe-right)` results in argument error unless I use
`(define-key (current-global-map) [right] #'my-maybe-right)`.

Comment: How do you get the error? What's the error? How are you evaluating this? If you look at the definition of `global-set-key` (e.g. with `M-x find-function RET global-set-key RET`) you'll see it's doing the exact same thing.